# Is there a difference between Clone and Import Vs Copying a DataTable

Tags: .net, datatable

Normally when I want to grab a copy of an existing `DataTable` I call the [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx) method are return the value to a new object.

I've been cleaning up some legacy code and noticed using [`Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) and then iterating through each row and calling `ImportRow` into the new `DataTable`.

```vb
'is this...
TempTable = myDataTable.Clone
For Each dr As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
    TempTable.ImportRow(dr)
Next

'the same as this...
TempTable = myDataTable.Copy
```

I'd like to clean it up and simplify by using the `Copy` method, but just want to make sure I'm not breaking anything.  Is there a difference between the two methods here about holding references or doing a deep vs. shallow copy?